# How do I download and install Pandas and Numpy for PyPy in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pypy

So I am using the Python interpreter PyPy as it makes my code run faster. However, everytime I try to run another code of mine, I get import error: No such module found. When I do a pip install pandas/numpy, it does not help as firstly the normal Python-2.7 folder already has it. And when I direct it to be installed directly to PyPy, the installation fails when it runs the setup.py file.

Could someone suggest another way in which I could get pandas and numpy to pypy? Thanks in advance!!

P.S. I have already tried: pypy setup.py install for pandas and numpy and it results in errors as well.

Comment: Consider using [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) which bundles up pandas, numpy and a ton of other packages into a single installation.

Comment: You have to the version adapted for `pypy`, if any.  Too much of the regular `numpy` is compiled `c` to work with pypy.

Comment: "Too much of the regular numpy is compiled C to work with pypy" --- that used to be true a few years ago, it no longer is

Comment: @confused_kid: running "pypy -m pip install numpy" works for me on pypy2 on Linux.  I'm told it also works in other cases.  Please tell us more about your platform and the errors you get (and the pypy version).

Comment: @AlexHristov If I simply download anaconda, will pypy be able to pick up the necessary libraries from there? Or do I need to take any additional steps? Sorry I am new to this and am not really sure how its going to work.

Comment: @ArminRigo I have tried that as well. It just gets stuck at the Running setup.py install for pandas ... \ section and then it throws a list of errors and warnings as well as my anti-virus detects virus in the file :( The virus detected is win32:Evo-gen and therefore I am afraid to declare it as false positive to see if this is whats hindering my installation. I am using pypy2 v5 for windows 10, 32 bit.

Comment: Can't do anything without (1) the precise pypy version, (2) the exact dump of everything you get up to and including the error message.

Comment: The exact version is pypy2-v5.10.0-win32 which I checked is compatible with pandas.  The error is:

pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(97) : error C2065: 'ssize_t' : undeclared identifier
pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(97) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'rv'
pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(97) : error C2065: 'rv' : undeclared identifier
pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(103) : error C2065: 'rv' : undeclared identifier
pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(104) : error C2065: 'rv' : undeclared identifier

Comment: ..continued error:

pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(115) : error C2065: 'rv' : undeclared identifier
pandas/_libs/src/parser/io.c(116) : error C2065: 'rv' : undeclared identifier
error: command 'C:\\Users\\Shrestha\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

I am also thrown with warnings such as :

warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'int64_t' to 'size_t', possible loss of data

Anti virus gives the message, we have moved groupby.pypy-41.pyd to virus chest because it was infected with Win32:Evo-gen [Susp].
@ArminRigo

Comment: @ArminRigo I am having issues in installing gcloud as well. Any idea what this means?

error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Users\\Shrestha\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the status of Pandas on Windows, but it looks like it doesn't work for shallow reasons and could be fixed.  You should probably open an issue in PyPy's own tracker:

https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/

Be sure to mention it's on Windows, and include the complete copy of everything you typed and what is output.